# Biasing of bipolar junction transistor (BJT) in CE configuration?

Tags: transistors

In a **Bipolar junction transistor** i understood how to bias the transistor in active state in **common base** configuration but facing problem in biasing it in **common emittor** configuration in active state.

I am getting confused how to reverse bias the base and the collector in **CE** configuration.

Can anyone please explain it taking n-p-n transistor as a reference.

Comment: Can you show what you tried? It's hard to tell what you're not understanding if we can't see what you've done that doesn't work.

Comment: I suggset that you draw a common emitter configuration circuit on a piece of paper. You might want to use Google and search for "common emitter circuit" to see what circuits are common. Then do some calculations on what the voltages and currents are. *I am getting confused how to reverse bias the base and the collector in CE configuration.* What if you simply make the voltage at the collector higher than the voltage on the base? For an NPN based common emitter that is.

Comment: As far as dc biasing of an npn transistor is concerned, there is no principle difference between common base and common emitter configuration. In both cases, the transistor needs a dc voltage between base and emitter , which in most cases is between 0.6 volts and 0.75 volts.